# Connect header image to navbar

Tags: html, css

So I have my navbar up top overflowing anything else. I want my header image to connect to it underneath but not follow the navbar when scrolling, just stay where it is. Here is a picture to show what I'm dealing with:

[image]

I want to eliminate that space in between the navbar and the header.

Here is my css:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.banner-img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <a><img class="banner-img" src="images/banner.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my navbar:

CSS:

```
ul.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.nav-right {
    float:right;
    list-style-type:none;
}

li.nav {
    float: left; /* Slides each element next to each other */
}

li.nav a {
    display: block;
    color: white; /* The text colour */
    text-align: center; /* This centers the text into each block */
    padding: 14px 16px; /* top and bottom paddings are 14px, and right and left paddings are 50px. */ 
    text-decoration: none; /* Ensures there is no decoration */
    font-family: "Comic Sans", Comic Sans MS, cursive;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a class ="active" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    <ul class="nav-right">
        <li class="nav"><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

And some more info that may play a part in this:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be the padding-top on your body. Your nav is less than 70px in height, so the `padding-top: 70px` makes a space appear between the image and your nav bar.

In order to fix that, you'd have to set the padding-top value to the exact height of your nav bar. You'd also need to make sure that your nav bar always has the same height, or that the padding-top value changes if the nav-bar height changes.

On my browser, the nav bar is 51px in height, so your body css would look like this:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 100px;
    padding-top: 51px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this makes perfect sense. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can fix like this
https://jsfiddle.net/p9vuz704/

There is two solution solve you're problem.

1. Put banner image code inside navbar code

   `<div class="navbar">
           ...
       <img class="banner-img" src="images/banner.png"/>
   </div>`

   .navbar {
     position: fixed; top: 0;
   }
2. just set image position as fixed and top: (navbar height)px